# Porque o "git checkout ." não altera os pacotes do node_module que eu inseri pelo npm?

Tags: git, npm

Eu fiz uma pequena "caca" no meu ambiente de testes, e o meu sistema simplesmente bugou inteiro, por que o npm está dando alguns bugs:

**Git Bash:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Console do Google Chrome:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pelo filezilla eu tenho os pacotes antigos, o package.json antigo e o node_module antigo, mas achei estranho fazendo git checkout eu não conseguir a voltar o meu estado de quando fiz o último commit.

**Obs: pelo que vi em alguns forúns de programação e no stackoverflow gringo, eu só teria que reinstalar alguns pacotes, mas não está dando o resultado esperado.**

Answer (score 2):

Por convenção, a pasta `node_modules/` é ignorada no versionamento de alguns projetos, portanto não é afetada pelos comandos do **Git**.

Você pode verificar no arquivo `.gitignore`, o caminho desta pasta estando lá, ela está ignorada.

Caso seja este o seu caso, para reinstalar as dependências, você pode deletar a pasta `node_modules/` e rodar o `npm install` novamente.