# Erro quando tento fazer um commit para github

Tags: git, github

aparece essa msg no git quando tento envia para o github

On branch origin
nothing to commit, working tree clean
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse problema acontece quando você não fez nenhuma modificação em arquivos rastreados pelo git. Você pode confirmar isso com o `git status`. Você realmente modificou algum arquivo?

Comment: na verdade esta aparecendo a mesma frase quando coloco o git status

Comment: e eu quero adicionar no github o arquivo com commit mas não consigo

Comment: Mas esse arquivo está dentro da pasta indicada? Se sim, dê uma olhada num arquivo chamado `.gitignore`. Tudo que fica nele é ignorado (ele **não** adicionará no `git add`)

Comment: esta os node modulos que coloquei

Comment: A pasta `node_modules` é, por convenção, ignorada, já que pode ser muito pesada e facilmente criada (com todo seu conteúdo) através do comando `npm install`. [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/283294/100416) tem uma resposta falando um pouco disso

Comment: no caso meu aparece essa msg para qq comando do git que eu faço

Answer (score 0):

fui na pagina do github aonde estrava meu repositorio e coloqueios comandos de importar os arquivos e origin e deu certo de manda os arquivos ,e depois realizei as alterações do commit pois constava informações de outros commit que tentei com esse comando:
git commit --amend -m "Minha nova[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] mensagem

so a parte selecionada que utilizei para resolver o problema.

Answer (score -1):

O terminal deixa bem claro, o git não rastreou nenhuma mudança ao comparar seu repositório com o repositório remoto. Você pode dar um *git status* para certificar se os dados foram mesmo modificados. Pode também dar um *git remote -v* para saber se o git está apontando para o repositório que você está dando seus commit. E para aparecer algo mais ou menos assim:

```
origin  https://github.com/username/Repositorio_que_voce_esta_trabalhando.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/username/Repositorio_que_voce_esta_trabalhando.git (push)
```

Caso não apareça algo assim, provavelmente o git nao aponta para o repositório que você está trabalhando

Comment: no caso o git não estava dando nenhuma ação ,por isso tive que manadr a força o push e depois comitar os commit de forma diferente no caso do status não aparecia os dados do repositorio nem log tb